# how do i create a new array if my arrays have the same id in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

how do i create a new array if my arrays have the same id in React
I'm confused about processing the array into 2 arrays if he has the same id, then what are the right steps so I can find a way out?

my array

```
   array = [
    {
      name : 'foo1',
      id_ : 3451,
      statuse : true
    },
    {
      name : 'foo2',
      id_ : 3451,
      statuse : false
    },
    {
      name : 'foo3',
      id_ : 3452,
      statuse : false
    },
    {
      name : 'foo1',
      id_ : 3452,
      statuse : true
    },
  ]
```

and the results I want

```
result = [
    [
      {
        name : 'foo1',
        id_ : 3451,
        statuse : true
      },
      {
        name : 'foo2',
        id_ : 3451,
        statuse : false
      },
    ],
    [
      {
        name : 'foo3',
        id_ : 3452,
        statuse : false
      },
      {
        name : 'foo1',
        id_ : 3452,
        statuse : true
      },
    ]
  ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a little unclear but I belive you want to group the elements of the array by the `id_` field of the element.

You can do this with the following snippet:

```js
const inputs = [
  { name : 'foo1', id_ : 3451, statuse : true },
  { name : 'foo2', id_ : 3451, statuse : false },
  { name : 'foo3', id_ : 3452, statuse : false },
  { name : 'foo1', id_ : 3452, statuse : true },
];

const ids = inputs.map(input => input.id_);
const uniqIds = [ ...new Set(ids) ];

const result = uniqIds.map(id => {
  return inputs.filter(input => input.id_ === id);
});

console.log(result);
```